# Píxel loop of a multispectral image

Tags: matlab

I have a multispectral image with 6 bands.

```
imagen1=imread('re_2008.tif')
size2=size(imagen1);
nrow= size2(1);
ncol= size2(2);
nband= size2(3);
```

What I want to do is get every pixel of every band (in the same position) with their value, do an interpolation and with a new value located in other wavelength, replace it. Maybe you understand me more if I show you the code.

```
imagen3_2 = zeros(nrow, ncol, nband);
var1= [1 2 3 4 5 6]'; %'

for row=1:nrow;
    for column=1:ncol;
        for band=1:nband;              
            v = imagen1(nrow(1),nband(2),:); v = v(:); 
            t= 0:100;

            interplan= interp1(var1, v, t,'cubic');
            y5 = interplan(5); % I get the value of the interpolation on this position
            y12 = interplan(12);
            y20 = interplan(20);
            y50 = interplan(50);
            y80 = interplan(80);
            y90 = interplan(90);

            imagen3_2(:,:,1)= (y5); % and I replace it
            imagen3_2(:,:,2)= (y12);
            imagen3_2(:,:,3)= (y20);
            imagen3_2(:,:,4)= (y50);
            imagen3_2(:,:,5)= (y80);
            imagen3_2(:,:,6)= (y90);
        end 
    end
end
```

I get the same value as a result, not for every pixel.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
imagen3_2 = zeros(nrow, ncol, nband);
var1= [1 2 3 4 5 6]'; %'

for row=1:nrow;
    for column=1:ncol;
            v = imagen1(row, column, :); v = v(:); 
            t= 0:100;

            interplan= interp1(var1, v, t,'cubic');
            y5 = interplan(5); % I get the value of the interpolation on this position
            y12 = interplan(12);
            y20 = interplan(20);
            y50 = interplan(50);
            y80 = interplan(80);
            y90 = interplan(90);

            imagen3_2(row,column,1)= (y5); % and I replace it
            imagen3_2(row,column,2)= (y12);
            imagen3_2(row,column,3)= (y20);
            imagen3_2(row,column,4)= (y50);
            imagen3_2(row,column,5)= (y80);
            imagen3_2(row,column,6)= (y90);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that Shai already answered your question, however if you are not really interested in variables `y5`, `y12` etc. there is a way to make the code compacter and easier to maintain:

```
imagen3_2 = zeros(nrow, ncol, nband);
var1= [1 2 3 4 5 6]'; %'

for row=1:nrow;
    for column=1:ncol;
            v = imagen1(row, column, :); v = v(:); 
            t= 0:100;

            interplan= interp1(var1, v, t,'cubic');

            y = [5 12 20 50 80 90];
            for i = 1:length(y)         
               imagen3_2(row,column, i)= interplan(y(i));% repace interpolation value
            end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency, try to avoid loops in Matlab, you can try something like this:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
y = imread('re_2008.tif');
y_size = size((y(:,:,1)));

xi = 0:100;
yi = zeros([y_size,numel(xi)]);

for i_pix=1:prod(y_size)
    [aux_x,aux_y] = ind2sub(y_size,i_pix);
    yi(aux_x,aux_y,:) = interp1(x,squeeze(y(aux_x,aux_y,:)),xi,'cubic');
end
```

Or even like this:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
y = imread('re_2008.tif');
xi = 0:100;

yi = arrayfun(@(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6) interp1(x,[y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6],xi,'cubic'), ...
y(:,:,1), y(:,:,2), y(:,:,3), y(:,:,4), y(:,:,5), y(:,:,6))
```

I couldn't check the code, so there could be errors; but it is just to give ideas about other kinds of implementation.